# How to echo filename in input type file using php

Tags: php

this is the HTML code

```
<input type="file" name="event_image" class="form-control ChangeEvntImage UploadEventImage tab5-required-check" value="<?=$v_image['image']?>">
```

This is my output:

[image: This is my output]

I want this:

[image: I want this]

Comment: did you check the value for $v_image['image'] ?

Comment: What if you do `value="<?php echo $v_image['image']; ?>">`

Comment: i want to show my image name when i go for update it, Please look into the last image

Comment: like 'no file chosen' to my file name

Comment: What does `$v_image['image']` contain? You want to show the file name before you upload? (Not possible in PHP, need to use Javascript for this)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html

Comment: Apart from that you can’t do it, it would make rather little sense as well - because then the user would upload the same file _again_ (provided it even still exists in the same location in their local file system) once they submitted this form - which is unnecessary to begin with, if they don’t want to _change_ what they have already uploaded.

Comment: use jquery onchange function to show the filename...

Answer (score 2):

You are not able to set a value of HTML File input because of security reason.
Please, check the answer of the older Stackoverflow post: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

As @kerbholz said you have to write javascript.May be this code help you to solve the your problem.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link class="jsbin" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />

</head>
<body>
      <input id="image" type="file" name="event_image" class="form-control ChangeEvntImage UploadEventImage tab5-required-check" value="<?=$v_image['image']?> ">
</body>
</html>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
   function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#image')
                    .attr('src', e.target.result)
                    .width(150)
                    .height(200);
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
```